# Variable not being assigned

Tags: php

This has been driving me crazy. When I put:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($clones); $i++) {
        $clones[$i]->attackGroup = $_POST['type'][$i];
}
```

$clones[2]->attackGroup does not get assigned. But when I put:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($clones); $i++) {
    if($i == 2) {    
        $clones[$i]->attackGroup = $_POST['type'][$i];
    }

}
```

It does.... How is this possible?

Comment: var_dump($_POST['type']) before for

Comment: Is attack group static?

Comment: whats the point of that?

Comment: attack group is undefined. just a var.

Comment: var_dump will show you what's in the `$_POST['type']` so that we can try to assist better.

Comment: how is clones indexed? what is sizeof $clones?

Comment: @Phas1c array(1) { [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } }

Comment: @OrangePill not sure what you mean by how  is it indexed. Its an array and its size is 8.

Comment: Consider showing us code related to the data objects and methods.

Comment: @Fred refer to my var_dump comment.....the index i'm trying to get is 2....therefore $i must be 2.

Comment: @Jonast92 this would be too much to post. I'm just looking for possible explanations to explain this phenomena given just what I have posted.

Comment: Phenomenas are based on different implementations in code. It's hard for us to tell you (obviously, since no one has answered this simple question) what's wrong if we can't see the array, we can't see what's getting assigned and based on what, other than what you show us. Sure it tells us a lot, but I'm not confident enough to answer based on this.